# Checkout and run SCM pipeline only on master node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I coded a generic pipeline which accepts several parameters in order to deploy releases from a pre-defined GitHub repository to specific nodes. I wanted to host this pipeline on a Jenkinsfile on GitHub, so I configured the job to work with a "Pipeline script from SCM". The fact is - when I try and build the job - the Jenkinsfile gets checked out on every node. Is it possible to checkout and execute the Jenkinsfile only on, say, the master node and run the pipeline as intended?

EDIT: As I stated before, the pipeline works just fine and as intended setting the job to work with a pipeline script. **The thing is when I try and change it to be a "Pipeline script from SCM", the Jenkinsfile gets checked out on every agent**, which is a problem since I don't have git installed on any agent other than master. I want the Jenkinsfile to be checked out only on master agent and be executed as intended. FYI the pipeline below:

```
def agents = "$AGENTS".toString()
def agentLabel = "${ println 'Agents: ' + agents; return agents; }"

pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Prep') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (agents == null || agents == "") {
                        println "Skipping build"
                        skipBuild = true
                    }
                                    
                    if (!skipBuild) {
                        println "Agents set for this build: " + agents
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        stage('Powershell deploy script checkout') {
            agent { label 'master' }
        
            when {
                expression {
                    !skipBuild
                }
            }
        
            steps {
                git url: 'https://github.com/owner/repo.git', credentialsId: 'git-credentials', branch: 'main'
                stash includes: 'deploy-script.ps1', name: 'deploy-script'
            }
        }
    
        stage('Deploy') {
            agent { label agentLabel }
        
            when {
                expression {
                    !skipBuild
                }
            }
        
            steps {
                unstash 'deploy-script'
            
                script {
                    println "Execute powershell deploy script on agents set for deploy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are requesting the impossible.

### Now:

your Jenkinsfile is inside your jenkins configuration and is sent as such to each of your agents. No need for `git` on your agents.

### Pipeline script for SCM:

Since you use `git`, SCM = `git`. So you are saying: my Pipeline needs to be fetched from a `git` repository. You are declaring the `Deploy` step to run on `agent { label agentLabel }`, so that step is supposed to run on another agent than master.
How would you imagine that agent could get the content of the Jenkinsfile to know what to do, but not use `git` ?

### What happens in Jenkins?

- Your master agent gets triggered that it needs to build
- the master agent checkouts the Jenkinsfile using `git` (since it is a **Pipeline script from SCM**)
- jenkins reads the Jenkinsfile and sees what has to be done.
- for the **Prep** stage, I'm not quite sure what happens without agent, I guess that runs on master agent.
- the **Powershell deploy script checkout** is marked to run on master agent, so it runs on master agent (note that the Jenkinsfile will get checked out with `git` two more times:

  - before starting the stage, because jenkins needs to know what to execute
  - one more checkout because you specify `git url: 'https://github.com/owner/repo.git'...`
- the **Deploy** stage is marked to run on `agentLabel`, so jenkins tries to checkout your Jenkinsfile on that agent (using `git`)...

Comment: I'm fine with "you can't do that in Jenkins", after all I'm fairly new to the product. It just seems weird to me that the "Pipeline script from SCM" option has a completely different behaviour compared to the "Pipeline script". Ambiguous at best.

Comment: the behaviour is not "completely" different. If you past the Jenkinsfile content inside your configuration, jenkins just copies it to the agent. If you say that your Jenkinsfile is inside SCM (git), he needs git to perform a checkout on all agents...

Comment: Ok, so if the "Pipeline script" option is just copying the script to the agent, then I could checkout the pipeline script with a git only on master and then execute it on the desired agents? Say, pipeline { agent none stage('checkout pipeline') { agent { label 'master'} steps { git url 'https://github.com/owner/pipeline-repo.git'... stash... } } stage('executing pipeline') { agent { label agentLabel } steps { unstash... run the pipeline } } } ?

Comment: no, once you are inside the execution of your pipeline, you cannot change its definition.

Comment: Marked as answer as it was helpful even though I couldn't get to the result I was trying to achieve (which by the way was impossible as stated by the author).

Answer (score 6):

I think that `skipDefaultCheckout` is what are you looking for:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }

    stages {
        stage('Prep') {
                steps {
                    script {
                            ........................
                    }
                }       
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look to the documentation:

***skipDefaultCheckout**
Skip checking out code from source control by default in the agent directive.*

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I still didn't test your solution, but seems definitely worth a look. Unfortunately I've been redirected to other tasks and another team is "facing the challenge", I promise I'll look into it. +1 for the contribution

Comment: That indeed solved the problem for me - new builds still checkout the pipeline from SCM on master, but then run without additional checkouts (except as configured in the pipeline's `checkout` step).

Comment: Yes, the key is to pretty much always use `skipDefaultCheckout` in the pipe's global `options` block, and then put `cleanWs()` and `checkout scm` at the start of your pipe. This makes sure your workspace is always clean and you only checkout on your intended node. Use `stash/unstash` to transfer any files from node to node.

Comment: great! works perfectly. Somehow it is hard for me to understand the Jenkins-documentation - don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scripted Pipeline to do this, it should basically look like this

```
node('master') {
    checkout scm
    stash includes: 'deploy-script.ps1', name: 'deploy-script'
}

def stepsForParallel = [:]
env.AGENTS.split(' ').each { agent ->
    stepsForParallel["deploy ${agent}"] = { ->

    node(agent) {
        unstash 'deploy-script'
    }
}
parallel stepsForParallel
```

Comment: The OP is already using a Scripted Pipeline and explicitly wants to change it to **"Pipeline script from SCM"**

Comment: The term may be confusing but Jenkins pipelines can be either "Declerative Pipeline" like in OP example, or "Scripted Pipeline" like above example. Both pipeline types can run from SCM

Comment: You are right about that. But to me it looks like the question of the OP still is that he would like to run his pipeline (scripted or declarative) from SCM.

Answer (score -1):

you can find all info about jenkins agent section [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent).
Shortly: you can call any agent by name or label.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'master'
  }
}
```

If it will not work for you, then you will need to set any label on master node and call it by label

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'master_label_here'
  }
}
```