# In Jenkins how do I specify SCM parameters for a scripted pipeline job without specifying script path?

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to define a scripted pipeline job providing a (stub) script in the job description but I'd like to provide SCM properties I can use for the `checkout(SCM)` command.

The approach and the background (I'd like to avoid multiple clones) can be looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583029/1668622).

Unfortunately it looks like I can only set those properties *together* with a script path  by selecting "Pipeline script from SCM" (rather than "Pipeline script" only which allows me to directly provide the script in the job).

*Configuration interface for "Pipeline script from SCM":*
[image: Pipeline script from SCM]

*Configuration interface for "Pipeline script":*
[image: Pipeline script]

Is there a way to provide all those SCM properties *and* write a script directly in the job?

**Update**

My current (working) approach is to have an `scm` object instantiated like this in the generic stub:

```
 scm = [
    $class: "GitSCM",
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credentialsId: "some-id",
        url: "ssh://ci-user@git-server/project",
        refspec: <something-calculated-from-params>,
    ]],
    branches: <something-calculated-from-params>,
    browser: [$class: 'GitWeb', repoUrl: <repo-url>],
    extensions: [
        [$class: 'CloneOption', reference: <url-to-reference>, timeout: 20],
        [$class: 'PathRestriction', includedRegions: <values>],
        [$class: 'DisableRemotePoll'],
    ] 
]
```

and then use it like the generated `scm` object using `checkout(scm)`.

Comment: Do you have a [Snippet Generator](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/) option on the left-hand menu?

Comment: I have the snippet generator and I can select and configure a git clone there. What I'm missing is the ability to configure those details via UI..

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow. If you pick **pipeline script from SCM**, you fill in the details, including the /path/to/jenkinsfile. It must do a lightweight clone to read the jenkinsfile, then processes it as if it were an inline script. Or you can use the **snippet generator** to build up the script inline (or just freehand it). Maybe the [Remote Jenkinsfile Provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/) is of interest to you?

Comment: were you able to do this? i am trying to do the same - pull from git and configure with parameters

Comment: Yes somehow - the final stub just contains a snippet similar to the one I just updated my question with.

Comment: if i have in my script ai have a params.server_url,  how would i set that after pulling from git in an automated manner (i.e. not clicking build with parameters)?   that's the part im not clear on

Comment: What do you mean by "after pulling from git" - haven't you used `scm` by then already? Do you mean you want this job to be triggered by changes automatically and don't know how to associate this job with the git repository in the first place?